# Ubuntu 16.04 SSH RSA Keys work but only if password authentication is enabled (Putty)

Tags: 16.04, server, encryption, authentication, openssh

- I have keys setup on my Linux headless server and Putty on my Windows Desktop.
- I can connect and authenticate successfully with Putty and authentication is via RSA Keys.

However, if I disable password authentication in `sshd_config` (`PasswordAuthentication no`) when I try and connection with Putty I get:

```
Server refused our key
```

And yet, if I then enable password authentication again, the key authentication works!

In addition, if I reset permissions of the `/.ssh` folder and authorized keys to `0700` and `0644`, respectively.

I am able to disable password authentication and use the RSA Keys only until system reboot which then returns `server refused our key` again....

Comment: post the whole debug log if you want some insight. It is not possible to answer from these information.

Comment: the files in ~/.ssh must have 0600 permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH is allowing remote connections only after a local login to the server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/882303/ssh-is-allowing-remote-connections-only-after-a-local-login-to-the-server)

Answer (score 1):

I had the home directory encrypted, this seems to have been the cause. I re-installed and set up SSH again and it worked fine, as soon as the home directory is encrypted, ssh keys won't work without enabling password authentication in sshd.config - must be a workaround for this but for now this works for me.